# JSF, how to start a separated thread to handle pdf generation and directly render view

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I use typically a jsf page with some fields.User finally calls a function of a managed-bean with

```
 <h:commandButton value="Go" action="#{myManagedBean.myFunction}"/>
```

In myFunction, a pdf is generated with the flying saucer library and an email is sent with the pdf file as an attachment.

My problem:
PDF generation takes a while ...So when the user clicks the h:command button, data is sent, and the page is in processing
for a long time.....

How to render jsf view quickly to the user and start in a separate thread the processing of PDF (and send mail later).

Any Help would be appreciate !
Christophe .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question isn't really dependent on JSF nor spring. Since you have tagged your question with spring, have a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). `TaskExecutor` is abstract API for asynchronous processing. If you don't want a spring dependency, use `java.util.concurrent.Executor`, for example `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

With a single `ThreadPoolExecutor` for this task - a spring singleton for instance - you are able to control how many pdf generating threads can run in parallel by setting appropriate pool size.

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Reader r = generatePDF(someData);
    sendEmail(r, userData);
    r.close(); // in finally preferably
  }
}
```

If you wanted to update JSF GUI after pdf generation is done, you could try some push implementation but I would avoid this if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! exactly what I need, I just add before ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);